# Why does it provide 2 com.google.cloud/services/compute-engine/VmimageN1StandardCore measurements? I have only one instance running

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-billing

I am trying to analyze gcp billing report. I have created one GCP compute engine instance with (2-cores, 7.5 GB Ram). I am exporting billing report to csv. It is showing:
1.com.google.cloud/services/compute-engine/VmimageN1StandardCore and 2.com.google.cloud/services/compute-engine/VmimageN1StandardRam
                                                                           both of them twice. And again it is showing
 1.com.google.cloud/services/compute-engine/Licensed1000205Core and 2.com.google.cloud/services/compute-engine/Licensed1000205Ram
                                                                           with similar measurement quantities.
What is the significance of these entries? Is there some data dictionary for these measurement_ids?

Answer (score 0):

All Google Cloud Platform accounts get free billing and payments support. The best person to explain the charges would be someone from the billing team as they can look at your project and they are the specialists. You can contact them by following the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing/)